# Import JSON to MongoDB with Compass MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm using Compass MongoDB to connect to my MongoDB Atlas. I want to import json collection. When I hit import it says "Done" but nothing is happening. What could be the problem?

[image]

My json collection is an array of objects:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json syntax looks good, even for the _id, however - in my dbs, the _id is a hex string - that is, it's made up completely of numbers 0-9 and letters a-f, with no special characters like the dash/negative sign you have. I would make a sample file with 2 records, eliminate the _id, see if it imports.

If it does, then make a sample file with those 2 records, with the _id being hex strings, and see if it imports.

If all 4 of those docs (2 from each batch) import properly, the problem is the _id that's not a hex string.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was with $oid. I deleted them from json, data was imported and $oid autogenerated